# Using list comprehensions and exceptions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Okay lets say I have a list, and I want to check if that list exists within another list. I can do that doing this:

```
all(value in some_map for value in required_values)
```

Which works fine, but lets say I want to the raise an exception when a required value is missing, with the value that it is missing. How can I do that using list comprehension?

I'm more or less curious, all signs seem to point to no.

*EDIT* Argh I meant this:

```
for value in required_values:
 if value not in some_map:
  raise somecustomException(value)
```

Looking at those I cant see how I can find the value where the error occurred

Comment: very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> lets say i want to the raise an exception when a required value is missing, with the value that it is missing. How can i do that using list comprehension?

List comprehensions are a syntactically concise way to create a list based on some existing list—they're *not* a general-purpose way of writing any `for`-loop in a single line.  In this example, you're not actually creating a list, so it doesn't make any sense to use a list comprehension.

Comment: I agree now that i've looked more into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to consider duplicates and the values are hashable, use sets. They're easier, faster, and can extract "all" elements missing in a single operation:

```
required_values = set('abc') # store this as a set from the beginning
values = set('ab')
missing = required_values - values
if missing:
    raise SomeException('The values %r are not in %r' % 
                        (missing, required_values))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `missing = required_values - values` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use raise in a list comprehension. You can check for yourself by looking at [the grammar in the Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/expressions.html#comprehensions).

You can however, invoke a function which raises an exception for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another (ugly) possibility would be the `error_on_false` function:

```
def error_on_false(value)
    if value:
        return value
    else:
        raise Exception('Wrong value: %r' % value)

if all(error_on_false(value in some_map) for value in required_values):
    continue_code()
    do_something('...')
```

That's ugly. I'd use the `set` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about tonight. My use case is iterating over a list of objects and raising an error when the object was not of a specific type. My solution is to use a generator.

```
def iter_my_class(my_class_list):
    for c in my_class_list:
        if not isinstance(c, MyClass):
            raise ValueError('Expected MyClass')
        yield c
```

Then used as

```
classes = [c for c in iter_my_class(my_class_list)]
```

I wrote this on my phone. If that runs without errors you all owe me a beer.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly hack something together, but it is not particularly readable.

`(_ for _ in ())` defines a generator, from which you can use the `throw` method to raise any exception you want.

```
all((_ for _ in ()).throw(somecustomException(value)) for value in required_values if value not in some_map)
```

That said, readability aside, it doesn't make sense to use a list comprehension unless you're actually going to use the list. This might make more sense as something like:

```
map_values=[some_map[value] if value in some_map else (_ for _ in ()).throw(somecustomException(value)) for value in required_values]
```

But even then it probably makes more sense to handle the exception outside the loop. If you want to raise a custom exception for some reason you can just catch the KeyError and raise your own exception.

```
try:
    found_values=[some_map[value] for value in required_values]
except KeyError as e:
    raise somecustomException(e.args[0])
```

Answer (score -2):

While I think using sets (like nosklo's example) is better, you could do something simple like this:

```
def has_required(some_map, value):
  if not value in some_map:
    raise RequiredException('Missing required value: %s' % value)

all(has_required(some_map, value) for value in required_values)
```

Comment: That doesn't put the name of the missing value in the exception, which is the point of the question.

Comment: Now it doesn't work. The *all* bultin function fails with any list I try.