# Python exception handling in list comprehension

Tags: python, exception, list-comprehension

I have a Python function called `plot_pdf(f)` that might throw an error. I use a list comprehension to iterate over a list of files on this function:

```
[plot_pdf(f) for f in file_list]
```

I want to use try-except block to skip any possible errors during the iteration loop and continue with the next file. So is the following code correct way to do the exception handling in Python list comprehension?

```
try:
    [plot_pdf(f) for f in file_list]  # using list comprehensions
except:
    print ("Exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
    continue
```

Will the above code terminate the current iteration and go to the next iteration? If I can't use list comprehension to catch errors during iteration, then I have to use the normal `for` loop:

```
for f in file_list:
    try:
        plot_pdf(f)
    except:
        print("Exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        continue
```

I want to know if I can use try-except to do exception handling in list comprehension.

Comment: "I use a list comprehension to iterate over a list of files on this function" *cough* *COUGH* **COUGHCHOKERETCH**

Comment: Unless you are using the list produced by the list comprehension, stick with the for loop.

Comment: What's wrong with the `for` loop?

Comment: @poorsod: Nothing wrong with `for` loop, just want to see if I can use try-except block to terminate one iteration in list comprehension.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python#1528375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle exceptions in a list comprehension in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
try:
    [plot_pdf(f) for f in file_list]  # using list comprehensions
except:
    print ("Exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
    continue
```

If `plot_pdf(f)` throws an error during execution of comprehension, then, it is caught in the `except` clause, other items in comprehension won't be evaluated.

It is not possible to handle exceptions in a list comprehension, for a list comprehension is an expression containing other expression, nothing more (i.e. no statements, and only statements can catch/ignore/handle exceptions).

> Function calls are expression, and the function bodies can include all
>   the statements you want, so delegating the evaluation of the
>   exception-prone sub-expression to a function, as you've noticed, is
>   one feasible workaround (others, when feasible, are checks on values
>   that might provoke exceptions, as also suggested in other answers).

[More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. This helps me to understand more about the list comprehension.

Comment: @kiriloff, is there a technical reason why future version of comprehensions cannot include an `except` clause? eg `[x[1] for x in list except IndexError pass]`

Answer (score 13):

You're stuck with your `for` loop unless you handle the error inside `plot_pdf` or a wrapper.

```
def catch_plot_pdf(f):
    try:
        return plot_pdf(f)
    except:
        print("Exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

[catch_plot_pdf(f) for f in file_list]
```

Comment: I have some exception handling inside `plot_pdf()`. But that doesn't catch all errors. So I want to use exception handling outside the list comprehension. I just want to know if the try-except block takes any effects on list comprehension. If not, then I can only use regular for loop to catch out-most exceptions.

Comment: So use a regular for loop.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a `catch` object

```
def catch(error, default, function, *args, **kwargs):
    try: return function(*args, **kwargs)
    except error: return default
```

Then you can do

```
# using None as default value
result (catch(Exception, None, plot_pdf, f) for f in file_list)
```

And then you can do what you want with the result:

```
result = list(result)  # turn it into a list
# or
result = [n for n in result if n is not None]  # filter out the Nones
```

Unfortunately this will not be even remotely C speed, [see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816432/python-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-map-or-compress-calls-and-ignore-errors?noredirect=1#comment45904633_28816432)