# Python: what is the fastest way to map or compress calls and ignore errors?

Tags: python, performance, exception

I frequently encounter a problem where I need to apply a function to a large iterator of data, but that function sometimes raises a known error that I want to ignore. Unfortunately, neither list compressions nor the map function has a good way to handle errors.

What is the best way to skip/deal with errors quickly in python?

For example, say I have a list of data and a function, the function raises a `ValueError` whenever the data is a str. I want it to skip these values. One way to do this would be:

```
result = []
for n in data:
    try: result.append(function(n))
    except ValueError: pass
```

You could also do the same thing without the error checking like:

```
result = [function(n) for n in data]
```

or

```
result = list(map(function, data))
```

I want an c-compiled approach to accomplishing the above. Something in the spirit of

```
result = list(map(function, data, skip_errors=True))
```

The feature of `default=value` would also be useful, so that raised errors create a default value.

I'm thinking this might be something I need to write a Cython extension for.

Note: one solution would be for me to write the `catch` function I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610997/python-exception-handling-in-list-comprehension?nah=1#28816652) in c or cython. Then I could use it in list compressions and get the performance boost I want.

Comment: It's not a duplicate: the accepted answer is that you skip getting any data at all, and another comment suggests that you handle it within the function itself! (not c speed, unless your function is written in c/cython)

Comment: what is your function?

Comment: the "function" is currently a function that my user creates through a text box that is compiled into python and called repeatedly. So it can literally be anything.

Comment: Is the function written in python or is it cythonised?

Comment: the function is currently not cythonized, but it will hopefully be in the future through something like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Comment: By the way, it is a list *comprehension*.

Comment: Oh my god,  I've been reading and saying that wrong for years!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap your function in an error handler?

```
def spam(n):
    try:
        return function(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass
result = [spam(n) for n in data]
```

you can then add anything you want to the error handling (note that in this version it returns `None`, so you probably want to either filter the resulting list or return a default value). The same goes for using `map`.

Comment: not fast enough. This requires python `try: except:`, I want c-speed as much as possible.

Comment: I could just use my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610997/python-exception-handling-in-list-comprehension?nah=1#28816652  But also not fast enough!

Comment: @GarrettLinux How do you propose to handle the Python exception raised by `function` without using Python exception mechanism? And are you sure that this is a bottleneck?

Comment: see the Note I added. I am proposing I just write a cython extension to handle this, I just want to make sure nothing like it exists.

Comment: essentially I just wish that the map function had this built in

Comment: @GarrettLinux I am not sure that cython would help, the function would still be raising an exception, so you'd still lose speed (again, if the issue is really there).

Comment: If you want C speed, why are you writing this in Python?

Comment: @Evpok, Your error handling will end up adding None's to the list when exception's are raised.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham indeed it will. I mentioned it.

Comment: That will add overhead removing though so not exactly an improvement. I think the correct solution would be to cythinise the function itself.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not much overhead if you use a generator `result = [c for c in (spam(n) for n in data) if c is not None]`. Testing Noneity is not that expensive. Anyway, he said he wanted to use a default value.

Comment: Ideally I want this to be useable with functions that are already in C as well. Obviously cythonizing the function itself will speed things up (and eventually we hope to compile the python code users put in into C) but adding very fast error handling would be nice.  Think about it: if you already had a cython function and just wanted to do fast error handling, wouldn't you want something like this?

Comment: @kindall I want as much speed as python can give me, and we need to flexibility and dynamic attributes of python.