# Using "try" for a list loop operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of values, that can be string like "string" and can be numbers that are given in a string format as "2.3"

I want to convert strings of certain value to a number ("N/A"->-1) and to leave any other string untouched, moreover I need to convert the numbers that are given in a string, in the float format to string format ("1.0"->1)
etc.

I managed to do so if I first run all over the list and convert the N/A values to -1 like so

```
for i in list:
    if i=="N/A": 
        i=-1
```

and then run with

```
l = [int(i) for i in l]
```

But I still might have strings, other then "N/A" and I don't want to have trouble trying to convert them, and need to use try in the second loop. 
how can I do that?

This is the code i try but i gives me syntax error

```
l = [try: int(float(i)) except: pass] for i in l
```

Origin list example: ["1.0","N/A","lol"] i need it to be [1,-1,"lol"]

Comment: Can you give example of your list before and how you want it to look after?

Comment: @Idos , i added an example

Comment: You can't change the iterating index inside a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle exceptions in a list comprehension in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: @peter wood this is not a duplicate, this is another question, i don't do comparison here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def convert(value):
    if value == 'N/A':
        return -1
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

Then:

```
[convert(value) for value in values]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `try except`  , try to cast to `int` if a exception occurs and if it's `"N/A"` so it should be replace by `-1` :

```
li = ["1.0" , "N/A" , "12" , "2.0", "Ok"]

for i,v in enumerate(li):
    try:
        li[i] = int(float((v)))
    except:
        if(li[i] == "N/A"):
            li[i] = -1

li # [1, -1, 12, 2, "Ok"]
```

Comment: i still need to keep strings that are not "NA" and i want to do it in the elegant one row loop if possible

Comment: You have another strings like `"Ok"` and dont want to convert them to `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

**Do it in one loop.**

```
l = ["N/A", "3", "5", "6"]

for idx,val in enumerate(l):
    try:
        l[idx] = int(val)
    except:
        l[idx] = -1

print l
```

**Output**

```
[-1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: @captainshai it should but i think you should use Rogalski example cause its by far the best, here.

Answer (score 0):

You may encapsulate try-except statement in your own function and use it in list comprehension.

```
def try_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

l = [try_int(i) for i in l]
```