# Error handling for list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Is there a way to handle errors in a python list comprehension. Preferably I would have something like this where the last two values are represented by `None`:

```
values = [try i ["row"] except KeyError None for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]]
```

This throws a syntax error and the only way I can do it is:

```
values = []
for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]:
    try: values.append (i ["row"])
    except KeyError: values.append (None)
```

I hope there is a more 'neat' way of doing this because the current solution is not preferable due to having to append to a blank list when a list comprehension does this in such a nice way!

Comment: There is no generator anywhere in your code. Do you mean *list comprehension*?

Comment: 1) I have changed my question because I did mean list comprehension    2) I don't mind if I have `None` in the list because I am running checks on the returned values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot catch an exception from a list comprehension ([How can I handle exceptions in a list comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)). But given what you want to do you could use `get`:

```
values = [i.get("row") for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]]
```

if the key isn't found in the dictionary `get` returns `None`, exactly what you're looking for (it can return anything you want, just by passing the default value as second argument, see [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey))

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if key is `dictionary` in list comprehension and return `None` if it is not present:

```
key = 'row'
values = [i[key] if key in i else None for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle exceptions *directly* in a list comprehension, because `try` is a statement, not an expression.

However, you can abstract the `try` out into a separate function:

```
def tryirow(i):
    try: return i["row"]
    except KeyError: return None

values = [tryirow(i) for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]]
```

---

Of course in this case, as [Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49224383/908494) implies, you've just reimplemented the built-in `dict.get` method:

```
values = [i.get("row") for i in [{"row" : 1}, {"Row" : 0}, {}]]
```

But this shows how you can solve similar problems more generally: if there's a function that does what you want, call it; if not, write it.

---

And of course sometimes, "write out a `for` statement" is actually the right answer. Not everything *should* be written as a list comprehension, even many things that *can*. I don't think that's relevant here, but it's worth keeping in mind.

---

There was actually a proposal to add a `try` expression just like the one you're trying to write, [PEP 463](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/). Why was it rejected? Because almost all of the use-cases were "get-with-default-fallback" cases where the function you want already exists (like `dict.get`) or should exist. Nobody could come up with a common use case that wasn't better written with a separate function or an expanded-out `for` statement.

In a brand new language, I think it would make more sense to have a `try` expression and not have methods like `dict.get`, but in a language that already had `dict.get` for over a decade before anyone suggested a `try` expression (and almost two decades before anyone put together a concrete proposal), that would be a bad change to make.