# Convert all keys in dictionary to lower case with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a function to convert all keys in a dictionary to lowercase:

```
def lower_dict_keys(some_dict):
    """Convert all keys to lowercase"""
    result = {}
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        if type(key) == str:
            result[key.lower()] = value
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

So far so good. Then I thought, hm, this would be more elegant in a dictionary comprehension, so this is what I came up with:

```
def lower_dict_keys2(some_dict):
    return {key.lower(): value for key, value in some_dict.items() if type(key) == str}
```

This only works if all keys are strings. I there are numeric keys, they get dropped:

```
d1 = {'A':'foo', 'b':'bar', 1:'zip'}

print(lower_dict_keys(d1))

>>>{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 1: 'zip'}

print(lower_dict_keys2(d1))

>>>{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
```

So my question is: is it possible to write this function as a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the key is not a string?

Comment: Like in the original function, it should just be added to the dict unaltered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct translation of your code to a comprehension is:

```
{key.lower() if type(key) == str else key: value for key, value in some_dict.items()}
```

using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to determine the key for each key-value pair.

Using `if` *after* the `for` loop **filters** on elements; those elements that don't pass the `if` test are not included in the output.

You also want to avoid using `type(...) is`, use `isinstance()` instead; subclasses of `str` will support the `lower()` method too:

```
{key.lower() if isinstance(key, str) else key: value for key, value in some_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *expect* your keys to ordinarily be strings, a more appropriate solution would be to use a `try` / `except` clause.

Here we catch `AttributeError`, which will occur only for non-string elements.

```
def lower_dict_keys(some_dict):
    """Convert all keys to lowercase"""
    result = {}
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        try:
            result[key.lower()] = value
        except AttributeError:
            result[key] = value
    return result

d1 = {'A':'foo', 'b':'bar', 1:'zip'}

lower_dict_keys(d1)

# {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 1: 'zip'}
```

Unfortunately, this will not work with a dictionary comprehension, since [statements are not permitted in comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python) and [PEP-463 was rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/).