# Python list comprehension: Skip elements that raise exception

Tags: python, exception, list-comprehension

I want to apply a function in a list comprehension that does not "work" for certain values.
A simple example would be `[1/x for x in [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]]`.
I would like to write something that skips the `0` and returns the following list: `[-0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 0.5]`.

My best shot so far was wrapping the division in a `try` statement:

```
def try_div(x):
    try:
        return 1/x
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass

result_with_none = [try_div(x) for x in [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]]
result = [x for x in result_with_none if x is not None]
```

This seems a bit inconvenient. Can I rewrite `try_div` in a way that makes the list comprehension skip the `0` element?

*Remark:* In this simple example, I could of course write `[try_div for x in [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2] if x !=  0]`. This is not practicable in my actual use case, because it is not easy to check a priori which values will raise an exception.

*Remark 2:* In contrast to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python), I am fine with explicitly handling exceptions in a function (like `try_div`). My question is mostly about how I could combine the last two steps (`result_with_none = ...` and `result = ...`) into one.

Comment: What is inconvinient in your code? Looks classic (perhaps switch comprehension with generator and use filter as well, but that's small stuff).

Comment: Rather, could you clarify what you consider "convenient"?

Comment: Looks good to me. @kabanus stated the further possible ameliorations.

Comment: Introducing `None` values just to remove them in the next line feels complicated. I thought there might be a way to skip these elements directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle exceptions in a list comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first solution is clear, and that's the most important thing in python. Alternatively, how about a generator instead of a comprehension?

```
def try_div_itr(itr):
    for elem in itr:
        try:
             yield 1 / elem
        except ZeroDivisionError:
             pass

result = list(try_div_itr([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

---

You could even generalise this

```
def try_itr(func, itr, *exceptions, **kwargs):
    for elem in itr:
        try:
            yield func(elem, **kwargs)
        except exceptions:
            pass
```

---

```
x = [random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(100_000)]

%timeit [i for i in (try_div(i) for i in x) if i is not None]
42.6 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [i for i in [try_div(i) for i in x] if i is not None]
36.3 ms ± 154 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit list(try_div_itr(x))
25.3 ms ± 85.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit list(try_itr(lambda i: 1/i, x, ZeroDivisionError))  
34.7 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# but expect generic method to be slower anyway

%timeit list(try_itr((1).__truediv__, x, ZeroDivisionError))
28.7 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# remove lambda abstraction for speed
```

Comment: Will this be as fast as a list comprehension?

Comment: Faster -- see above