# One liner to get valid xml strings

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the following in one line list-comprehension?

```
from lxml import etree
valid_xml_strings = []
for xml_string in xml_strings:
    try:
        etree.fromstring(xml_string)
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError:
        continue
    valid_xml_strings.add(xml_string)
```

Comment: No, list comprehension syntax does not allow `try-except`, and it's for the better

Comment: @DeepSpace is it possible to see if something is valid xml without doing a try/except? Or is that the only way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python