# How to handle exceptions in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries:

```
length = {1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 5, 8: 0}

result = {1: 3.0, 2: 3.7416573867739413, 3: 7.874007874011811, 4: 6.4031242374328485, 5: 4.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 5.0, 8: 1.0}
```

When the keys match, I need to divide the result value by the length value. So for example:

```
Key = 1: 3.0 / 3
Key = 2: 3.7416573867739413 / 9
etc
```

For all keys in result. I have tried using the following dictionary comprehension:

```
sims = {k:lengths[k] / v for k, v in result.items()}
```

But I get an error for `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

I then tried to avoid comprehension with an ugly code, and use:

```
for dot_key, dot_val in result.items():
    for length_key, length_val in lengths.items():
        if dot_key == length_key:
            try:
                currVal = float(dot_val / length_val)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                currVal = 0
            cosine_sims = {dot_key:currVal}

print(cosine_sims)
```

But I only get a result for `Key = 8`

```
{8: 0.0}
```

These SO posts indicate you cannot use `Try...Catch` in comprehension, so how can I achieve the desired result by dividing one value by another with the same key in two different dicts?

[How to handle exceptions in a list comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528237/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-a-list-comprehensions)

Comment: just change the last line cosine_sims[dot_key]=currVal

Comment: `the last line` can you show in an example please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can test for `0` with an inline `if`:

`lengths[k] / v if v != 0 else 0` directly in the comprehension

Comment: compared to my answer below, which is a fix, this answer solves the problem. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The last line, you are overwriting the dictionary. Instead append to the dictionary by using the following syntax.

inplace of

```
cosine_sims = {dot_key:currVal}
```

use

```
cosine_sims[dot_key]=currVal
```